# iOS - GitHub Firebase Authentication

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

I'm currently trying to implement GitHub Authentication via Firebase in an iOS app.

I've read through the docs and figured out what I have to do. I'm having trouble though, in implementing the communication between my app and the WebView where I authorize the application to get user's data. I currently have this code:

```
let url = urlComponents.url! // https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize + scope

// Not quite sure if I should use open(_:options:completionHandler:) to handle this operation.
guard UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else {
    return
}
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

What this code does is bring the user to the browser with the GitHub authorization screen, type the password and then a blank screen shows up. Inspecting the URL in this blank screen, I've found out that it contains the parameter it should have, but I'm not quite sure how to pass this parameter to my code so I can proceed with the authentication.

Firebase doc says I should implement a Custom URL scheme to handle the OAuth callback, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, solution was to edit GitHub's Authorization callback URL to have my custom URL scheme and then proceed through the documentation flow.

Comment: I can't get GitHub to trigger the callback, I can trigger it from Safari on the Simulator, but GitHub never calls it. Any tips?